# Should I keep Sqlite connection open?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

Should I be keeping sqlite connections open or should I close it every time I'm done with my batch queries?

Update: This is specific to iPhone/iOS if that makes a difference.

Comment: You don't provide much information. It all depends on how long between your queries, how much data you have retained, etc. etc.

Comment: Open once and close once, it will be easy to handle rather than closing and opening too many times. But if you are not going to use, then do free resources.

Comment: My app will generally be accessing the sqlite DB as frequently as users interact with the app. i.e. when user touches a button, table row etc. I'm wondering if it is better to keep the connection alive throughout the entire life of the app or open and close as needed. Especially since I've been reading that once you close connections sqlite doesn't remember previous execution plans there could be a performance hit when opening-closing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My general recommendation given that the DB interaction is user driven, I'd say open, do your activities, close it and then return to the user. This leaves nothing up in the air. There tends to be an over-emphasis on performance. The best approach on single user applications I find is to assume that performance is going to be fine, and then prove it otherwise.

One of the ways in which to prove this to yourself is right some test code to time how long it's taking to open and close a connection. Next is to try to sets of actions, one with each strategy. This should convince you.

The downsides to leaving your connection open generally outweighs (again, in single user applications) the benefits of keeping it open.

That's my 2 cents,

Comment: That is a very sensible approach. As a developer, I always have to fight the tendency to do pre-optimization which usually causes more headaches.